# Jackson not de-serializing dates properly?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have the following field in my Java class to record timestamps:

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT")
private Date timestamp;
```

This object is created and persisted in a database. This works fine, but when fetching the record from the DB which contains the correct date, Jackson de-serializes the JSON incorrectly by always setting the month and day to 12-30.

e.g. if I create a record with this timestamp:

```
2020-01-02 12:30:00
```

Jackson will deserialize it as:

```
2020-12-30 12:30:00
```

This happens every time and I don't know what's causing it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Instead of `YYYY` use `yyyy` or `uuuu`

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks. Is there a list of all possible values one can use?

Comment: maybe starting from documentation is good here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: How do you know that you have created a record with `2020-01-02 12:30:00` as the timestamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is mixing up minutes vs. months among other things. See the doc for [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

You probably want: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT")`